# Change value to opposite with exclamation mark Swift

Tags: swift

I want have bool variable - isChecked.

What i want is, to set opposite value to that variable like that:

```
(viewModel.arrValues[row] as! TestItem).isChecked = ((viewModel.arrValues[row] as? TestItem)?.isChecked)!
```

Logic is simple, ! mark suppose to present opposite value. But above code not work. Why?

Comment: The `!` goes in front (`!x` rather than `x!`).

Comment: Define "does not work".  And what happens if you put the `!` in front of the value you want the opposite of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because putting an exclamation mark **after** a variable marks force unwrapping. In general, putting the exclamation mark after an expression means forcing something (force casting with `as!` or force unwrapping for optionals, etc.).

You have to put it **before** the value to negate a boolean expression.

`(viewModel.arrValues[row] as! TestItem).isChecked = !((viewModel.arrValues[row] as? TestItem)?.isChecked)`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the after equal

```
(viewModel.arrValues[row] as! TestItem).isChecked = !((viewModel.arrValues[row] as? TestItem)?.isChecked)
```